# how do I generate an ordered list of vectors in R?

Tags: r, sorting, vector, ranking

In my data I have a list of made-up words and their rating by 30 individuals on a scale 1-5.

I have assigned the mean value of the word's rating to individual vectors as follows

```
dox.mean = c(mean(doxrating))
noi.mean = c(mean(noirating)) 
wostaro.mean = c(mean(wostaro$rating))
```

Now I want to use R to generate a list of the vectors in descending order.

When I try

`sort(dox.mean, noi.mean, wostaro.mean)`,

it returns the error message:

`Error in sort(dox.mean, noi.mean, daishu.mean) : 'decreasing' must be a length-1 logical vector`.

Did you intend to set 'partial'?

when I use `order(dox.mean, noi.mean, wostaro.mean)` it just returns: `[1] 1`.

How can I generate this list? I am a bit of a novice so simple terms would help!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of doxrating, noirating etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sort function in R deals with vectors.

For instance, `x <- c(1,2,3,4), sort(x)` or `sort(c(1,2,3,4))` generates the same right results. But for sorting a `data.frame`, you have to go one extra step:

1. Let's say your data frame has a name mydata: get a vector for the column by which you want sort your data frame; In your case, it can be like this:

   ```
   sort_dox <- sort(mydata$dox.mean), sort_noi <- sort(mydata$noi.mean), sort_wos <- sort(mydata$wostaro.mean)
   ```
2. use subset to get your sorted results:

   ```
   mydata[c(sort_dox, sort_noi, sort_wos)]
   ```
3. You can add `T` or `F` to chose descending or ascending sorting method.

Comment: I see no mention of the data being in `data.frame` form in the question, and the title suggests they want an ordered list.  Also, your subset in part 2 probably  will not work with real data

Comment: no matter the data is data.frame or matrix, we can still use the subsetting way.you reminds me that i forgot a comma in the subset. It should be: mydata[,c(sort_dox, sort_noi, sort_wos)]
Thanks